# How to repeat the simulation 1000 times to have 1000 different datasets

Tags: simulation, logistic-regression

I have 1 binary covariate x and want to use logistic regression to get the outcome y binary using the logistic formula. Then after that, I want to simulate a data on the basis of the probability from the logistic equation

I have tried and I am able to simulate the first data but repeating the process and adding subject id and simulation number is giving me the problem.

```
simulation  id  y   x
1   1   1   0
1   2   0   1
1   3   0   0
1   4   1   1
1   5   0   1
2   1   1   1
2   2   0   0
2   3   1   1
2   4   1   1
2   5   1   0
3   1   1   1
3   2   1   0
3   3   1   0
3   4   0   0
3   5   0   1
```

The code is as follows:

```r
nsample <- 100
set.seed(1234)
id <- rep(1:nsample)
p <- 0.01
b0 <- log(p/(1-p))
b1 <- 0.5
b2 <- 0.1
b5 <- -4
x1 <- rbinom(nsample, 1, 0.4)
x2 <- rbinom(nsample, 1, 0.6)

z2 <- b0 + b1*x1+b2*x2
p_vector <- 1/(1+exp(-z2))
y <- rbinom(n = length(nsample), size = 1, prob = p_vector)
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the code which you have tried to simulate the first data

Comment: @Martin I am failing to put the code that I did. It is always giving me an error when I put the code between `  `

Comment: Paste the code into the question, hightlite it, and then press Ctrl+K, this will indent each line with 4 spaces which causes it to be displayed as code (do this instead of trying to use ```)

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. I have pasted the code